# Error 998 (Invalid access to memory location) for when calling GetPointerFrameTouchInfo

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I am trying to call the `GetPointerFrameTouchInfo` function to get the pointer count but the function seems to fail with

> Error 998 (Invalid access to memory location).

Any idea why that is happening and how I can resolve it?
I am trying to call the same inside the hook procedure `GetMsgProc` as mentioned below:

```
LRESULT WINAPI GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LPMSG lpMsg = (LPMSG)lParam;
    UINT32 pointerId = GET_POINTERID_WPARAM(lpMsg->wParam);
    switch (lpMsg->message)
    {
    case WM_POINTERUPDATE:
        UINT32 *pointerCount;
        POINTER_TOUCH_INFO *pointerTouchInfo;
        TCHAR outputLogTouchTst[100];

        if (GetPointerFrameTouchInfo(pointerId, pointerCount, pointerTouchInfo) == 0)
        {
            _stprintf(outputLogTouchTst, _T("Hook: The error code for proc is %d"), GetLastError());
            OutputDebugString(outputLogTouchTst);
            return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        _stprintf(outputLogTouchTst, _T("Hook: The count of pointers is %d"), pointerCount);
        OutputDebugString(outputLogTouchTst);
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(getmsghook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: You never allocated any memory for `pointerCount` or `pointerTouchInfo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring pointer variables but never setting them to point to anything. You should just declare ordinary variables, and pass the addresses to the function.

```
constexpr maxpointers = 32;
UINT32 pointerCount = maxpointers;
POINTER_TOUCH_INFO pointerTouchInfo[maxpointers];

if (GetPointerFrameTouchInfo(pointerId, &pointerCount, pointerTouchInfo) == 0)
```

It's not necessary to use `&` for `pointerTouchInfo`; since it's an array, it automatically decays to a pointer when used as a function argument.

Comment: I am getting another error on doing that, i.e., list iterator not decrementable

Comment: This is the answer to the question that you asked

Comment: @Wolverine There's no list iteration in the code you posted, that must be unrelated code.

Comment: @Barmar: Apologies, I take that back. I am getting 'list iterator not decrementable' for WM_POINTERDOWN. And I am getting Error code 5 (Access Denied) for WM_POINTERUPDATE, which is our current issue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My goal here is to successfully run the function GetPointerFrameTouchInfo() to get the pointer count, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: I said nothing of your goal. I explained that the question you asked has been answered. This site is not for extended and evolving help writing your programs. It is for Q&A of a single question. Do you agree that your original question has been answered?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Agreed